# How to detect non existing class in use statement

Tags: php, static-analysis

How can I detect than class `NonExistingClass` does not exist?

I'm currently checking out features from PhpStan, Phan, Composer but nothing so far.

A developer removes code that calls `NonExistingClass` in class `A` and removes whole class `NonExistingClass` but does not remove use statement in class `A`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Model\NonExistingClass;

class A
{
}
```

How to detect this scenario during static analysis?

Comment: By trying to instatiate or use the class.

Comment: Nope. The case is that a developer removes code that calls `NonExistingClass` in class `A` and removes whole class `NonExistingClass` but does not remove use statement in class `A`

Comment: PhpStorm shows invalid `use` directives as errors but other than that `use` are just type "shortcuts" they don't need to be valid.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you, but IDE features is not something we should rely on. I want a static analyze tool for this problem.

Comment: Maybe [php mess detector](https://phpmd.org/) has a rule for that. Not sure haven't checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't detect nonexistent class in `use` statement because it might be a namespace.

What you can do is to detect unused uses in a file which is actually the case in your code example. Check out `SlevomatCodingStandard.Namespaces.UnusedUses` sniff for PHP_CodeSniffer in [slevomat/coding-standard](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard#slevomatcodingstandardnamespacesunuseduses-).

If the nonexistent class in a `use` statement is actually used in the file, PHPStan will tell you. See an example here: https://phpstan.org/r/1f05520e-88fe-4a61-9d05-018b466e640d

Comment: Thank you. Although it's not the answer I was hoping for, the information that it might be a namespace is good enough for me to abandon my problem.