# How with larastan show invalid declarations of classes?

Tags: laravel

Using larastan on laravel site I wonder if there is a way to show errors on declarations of classes which are
a) declared but not used in some class ?
b) invalid declarations, say class was removed , but declarations was left ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.28.0",
"nunomaduro/larastan": "^2.6.4",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably this will help you to find the proper solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59012302/7155723